# How to find derivative of an integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

So I am given
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^x e^{t^2}\ dt\right)$$

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: The derivative with respect to $x$ is $e^{x^2}$ following the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements)

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental theorem of calculus is helpful for here.  So suppose $G$ is the antiderivative of $e^{t^2}$.  Then we know that $\int_{0}^x e^{t^2} dt = G(x) - G(0)$.

We can then differentiate this.  Doing so, we get $G'(x) = e^{x^2}$, since $G(0)$ is constant and therefore vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT :**

Use [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this rule:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_0^xG(t)dt=G(x)+\int_0^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}G(t)dt=G(x)+0=G(x)$, where $G(t)=e^{t^2}$